DateTimePicker raises ValueChanged twice on DropDown
It looks like DateTimePicker raises ValueChanged twice:

once with MaxDate
once with current Value

on DropDown opened, if Value is not the MaxDate.
To reproduce drop DateTimePicker to the form, put
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(2024, 5, 31);
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = new DateTime(2024, 6, 2);
dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.MaxDate.AddHours(-1);

to the Load event handler.
Wire up ValueChanged event and add some debug output:
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss:ms") + " ::  " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + " __ " + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortTimeString());
}

Each time the DropDown being opened the event ValueChanged fired twice (except Value is MaxDate, in this case no ValueChanged being raised as expected).
Is there any setting, which triggers this odd behavior, or is it a "by design" bug?

if you are only looking for a solution, use the dateTimePicker1_closeup event. it only gets called once.

I suppose closeup will not be called on manual input/change.

thats true. maybe the leave event is better

@shingo What do you mean with current date? You can select each shown date in the DateTimePicker (except MaxDate) and afterwards ValueChanged will be called twice on each DropDown opens.

When you set as MaxDate a date/time that predates the current, the .NET Control receives a notification (DTN_DATETIMECHANGE), which lets you know about this condition (unless the selected date is the same as MaxDate). This is by design. To change this behavior, build a Custom Control, intercept WM_REFLECT + WM_NOTIFY, get the NMHDR struct from LParam. When the code member is DTN_DATETIMECHANGE, read NMHDR as NMDATETIMECHANGE, then make your own decision on how to handle the notification

@Jimi The behavior is the same when I set value first and then MaxDate. I try currently to build custom control with analyses of notification messages, but there are several different cases (notification not always the same) :( Somehow I have a feeling, that I do a job for Microsoft developer.

It doesn't matter when you set the Value, what matters is that MaxDate precedes the current Date (it's in the past). That's when you start getting those notifications

By which logic twice notification ValueChanged on each opening of DropDown is dependent on that fact, that MaxDate precede the actual date, even if the value in the min-max range?

DateTimePicker is a Win32 System Control. Maybe you want to know that the current configuration prevents your users (or the System itself) from setting a date that is at least the current. The Control notifies you of this condition (and keeps on adjusting)

Search for a workaround ended up with a control derived from DateTimePicker and overriding the WndProc. I'm not so fit in this Win32-"notification" stuff, but after some analysis suite algorithm could be determined.
This control does only raise ValueChanged, if the value is really changed (from code, selection in calendar, switch the month in calendar, manual input), all other cases are filtered out.
In my opinion it's a bug by WinForms wrapper, if control comes from Win32 library. They should write something like code below to provide a control to the developers, which works correctly.
internal struct NMHDR
{
    internal IntPtr hwndFrom;
    internal uint idFrom;
    internal uint code;
}
internal struct NMHDRx64
{
    internal IntPtr hwndFrom;
    internal IntPtr idFrom;
    internal int code;
}

internal class DateTimePickerFixed : DateTimePicker
{
    //#define MCN_FIRST   (0U-746U)// monthcal
    //#define MCN_SELCHANGE  (MCN_FIRST - 3)  
    private const uint MCN_SELCHANGE = 4294966547u;     // 4294966547u == (uint)-749
    private const uint PGN_LAST = 4294966346u;          // 4294966346u == (uint)-950

    //#define NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE (NM_FIRST-16)
    private const uint NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE = 4294967280u; // 4294967280u == (uint)-16
    private const uint UNKNOWN_NOTIFICATION = 4294966347u; // 4294966347u == (uint)-949 ????

    private const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E;

    private bool _isSendingUnnecessaryValueChanged = false;
    private bool _acceptDateSelection = false;

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        if (_isSendingUnnecessaryValueChanged)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RETURN " + Value.ToString());
            return;
        }

        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NOTIFY)
        {
            if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
            {
                HandleWmNotify((uint)((NMHDRx64)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDRx64))).code);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleWmNotify(((NMHDR)m.GetLParam(typeof(NMHDR))).code);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private void HandleWmNotify(uint p_nmhdrCode)
    {
        if (p_nmhdrCode == PGN_LAST)
        {
            _acceptDateSelection = true;
            _isSendingUnnecessaryValueChanged = false;
        }
        if (p_nmhdrCode == MCN_SELCHANGE && !_acceptDateSelection)
        {
            _isSendingUnnecessaryValueChanged = true;
        }
        if (p_nmhdrCode == UNKNOWN_NOTIFICATION || p_nmhdrCode == NM_RELEASEDCAPTURE)
        {
            _acceptDateSelection = false;
            _isSendingUnnecessaryValueChanged = false;
        }
    }
}

